# bash: Find the values from set

Tags: bash

I can use the `set` command to change bash shell options, e.g.:

```
set -ex
```

Is there a command to check that the `-e` and `-x` options have been set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$-` in a short from, and you can check the `$SHELLOPTS` for a comma separated list of options.

```
echo $SHELLOPTS
braceexpand:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:vi

set -x
echo $SHELLOPTS
braceexpand:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:vi:xtrace
                                                                       ^^^^^^
set +x
set -v
echo $SHELLOPTS
braceexpand:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:verbose:vi
                                                                    ^^^^^^^
```

etc...

for the list, check: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Answer (score 2):

From `man bash`: "The current set of options may be found in $-", so use

```
echo $-
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `$-` contains all the shell options:

> ```
>   - Expands to the current option flags as specified upon invocation, 
>     by the set builtin command, or those set by shell itself (such as 
>     the -i option).
> ```